# Drag onto hidden overlay to display overlay

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dropzone

I am using a js library `react-dropzone` to allow users to drag and drop files.

The user can click a button to open an overlay to drag and drop files, but I also want the ability to allow the user to drag onto the window to then display the window.

At the moment, this does not work as it does not recognise the `onDragOver` event listener as currently the overlay is set to `display: none` so there is no inherited height so I'm dragging onto the screen but to the overlay as it's currently got a height and width of 0.

Here is my `UploadOverlay` component using `react-dropzone`

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./UploadOverlay.scss";
import CloseIcon from "./CloseIcon";
import UploadIcon from "./UploadIcon";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import axios from "axios";

const UploadOverlay = props => {
  const [dragEnter, setDragEnter] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(props.active);
  const MODAL_OPEN_CLASS = "UploadOverlay--Open";

  const config = {
    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
      let progress = Math.round(
        (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
      );
      if (progress === 100) {
        props.onClose();
      }
    }
  };

  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    setDragEnter(false);
    if (acceptedFiles.length === 0) {
      props.onClose();
    } else {
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", acceptedFiles[0]);
      //handle 500 errors.
      axios
        .post("/api/website-user/avatar", formData, config)
        .then(response => {
          props.onSuccess(response);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.active) {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
      document.body.classList.add(MODAL_OPEN_CLASS);
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove(MODAL_OPEN_CLASS);
    }
    setActive(props.active);
  }, [props]);

  const onDragEnter = () => {
    setDragEnter(true);
  };

  const handleDropzoneClick = event => {};

  const handleCloseClick = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    props.onClose();
  };

  const content = (
    <Dropzone
      accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
      onDrop={onDrop}
      onDragEnter={onDragEnter}
      onDragOver={() => {
        document.body.classList.add(MODAL_OPEN_CLASS);
        setActive(true);
      }}
      onDragLeave={() => {
        document.body.classList.remove(MODAL_OPEN_CLASS);
        setActive(false);
      }}
    >
      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
        <div
          className={
            "UploadOverlay " +
            (active ? "UploadOverlay--Active" : "") +
            (dragEnter ? " UploadOverlay-DragEnter" : "") +
            " UploadOverlay--Desktop"
          }
          {...getRootProps({
            onClick: handleDropzoneClick
          })}
        >
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <a className="UploadOverlay--CloseIcon" onClick={handleCloseClick}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </a>
          <div className="UploadOverlay--Content">
            <UploadIcon />
            <h1>Upload a Photo</h1>
            <h2 className="UploadOverlay--ContentMsgDesktop">
              Drag and Drop your image to upload it to your profile.
            </h2>
            <h2 className="UploadOverlay--ContentMsgMobile">
              Tap anywhere to upload an image to your profile.
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Dropzone>
  );

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(content, document.body);
};

export default UploadOverlay;
```

Here is my css

```
.UploadOverlay {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   display:none;
}

body.UploadOverlay--Open {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.UploadOverlay.UploadOverlay--Active {
   background:rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.75);
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   z-index:99;
   display:block;
}

.UploadOverlay.UploadOverlay-DragEnter {
   background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.UploadOverlay .UploadOverlay--CloseIcon {
   position: absolute;
   right:25px;
   top:25px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.UploadOverlay .UploadOverlay--Content {
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   -ms-flex-pack: center;
   -ms-flex-align: center;
   -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-flow: column;
}

.UploadOverlay .UploadOverlay--Content h1 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 44px;
   line-height:44px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #666666;
   margin:35px 0px 35px 0px;
   padding:0px;
   text-align: center;
}

.UploadOverlay .UploadOverlay--Content h2 {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   color: #666666;
   max-width:325px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss at the moment. I've had tried setting the `opacity` of `.UploadOverlay` to `0` but then I cannot click on any elements on the screen other than the overlay. I then tried setting the `z-index` of `.UploadOverlay` to `-1` then I could not drag onto the screen.

Perhaps, I am going the wrong way around this structurally? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/842kxvyrz8) if you would like to try it out for yourself.